# How to obtain and then iterate an array of checkboxes in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a table that has 8 columns in it. The last column has a `<th>` header of **Refactor?** and simply displays a checkbox for each row in the table. If the user wants to Refactor a particular record in the table, they check the row's **Refactor?** checkbox and then submit the the form.

I am trying to implement a "Check All" checkbox above the table whereby the user clicks the "Check All" checkbox, and every row in the table gets its Refactor? checkbox checked. I am trying to achieve this in jQuery, and have gotten this far:

```
$("#checkAll").click(function() {
    alert("Check All has been checked!");

    var checkboxArray = null;
    $.each(checkboxArray, function(key, value) {
        $(key).prop("checked", true);
    });
});
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, however when I comment-out everything underneath the `alert` I can successfully get the alert dialog popping up when I click the "Check All" checkbox, so I've gotten that far.

I'm trying to obtain an array (`checkboxArray`) of all the *Refactor?* checkboxes in the table. Once I have that array, I just need a way to iterate through each checkbox and set its `checked` property to true. But I'm having a tough time connecting the dots here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show your HTML, please?

Comment: Simplest solution, give all "Refactor" checkboxes a class (eg: "refactor"), then you can iterate over the checkboxes with `$('.refactor').each(function(element){...});` Or, more simply, `$('.refactor').prop('checked', true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 approaches, you can check ALL checkboxes

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
```

or you can give those refactor boxes a class and only check those

```
$('.refactorClass').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, but @Bot's was simplest. Everyone gets +1 for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just select the `:checkbox` of all `th:last-child`  in the table, and use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

```
$("#checkAll").click(function() {
    alert("Check All has been checked!");

    $("#myTable th:last-child :checkbox").prop("checked",true);
});
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/9BRA3/

Answer (score 0):

This would be alot cleaner if you add a class to all your checkbox's like selection then you can do

```
$("#checkAll").click(function() {
   $(".seleciton").attr("checked", true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're trying to put them in an array first.

[This works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/kBmA5/2/):

```
$('#checkall').click(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Given that they are in the 8th column, you can do it as follows:

```
$("#checkAll").click(function() {
    alert("Check All has been checked!");

    $('#yourtable td:nth-child(8) :checkbox').each(function() {
         $(this).prop("checked", true);
    });
});
```

See working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9BRA3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#checkAll").click(function() {
    alert("Check All has been checked!");

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not($(this)).prop('checked' , this.checked);
});
```

If these are the only checkboxes in your page then you can use the above method. No need of iterating in the first place..

```
$("#checkAll").click(function() {
      alert("Check All has been checked!");

      $('tbody input[type="checkbox"]').not($(this)).prop('checked' , this.checked);
 });
```